# Searching for prime candidates

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

For some additional excitement, I've been searching for primes $p \gg  q = 104729$, where $q$ is of course the ten-thousandth prime. It seems that the best way to search for prime candidates $p$ is to do trial division $p \pmod {\ell }$ for all $\ell $ belonging to the set of all primes between $2$ and $q$, and if $p \not\equiv 0 \pmod{\ell}$, check that $2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. If so, declare that $p$ might be prime. There is obviously no point in computing $2^{p-1} \pmod{p}$ if $3 \mid p$. Competing with the time it takes to run Mathematica's PrimeQ[ ], in Python 2.73 I wrote something like:

```
from numpy import *
primes=array([2,3,...,104729])
def trialdivandfermat(p):                   
    z=0                                                                    
    for q in range(0,9999):
        if p%int(primes[z])==0:
            break
        else:
            z=z+1
            if z==9999:
                if pow(2,p-1,p)==1:
                    return p
                break 

for p in range(1+10**1000,10**10000,2):
    trialdivandfermat(p)
```

Specifically searching for primes of the form $p = m^n \cdot h \pm 1$, $m$ odd, $h < m^n$ even, I have written that into my function trialdivandfermat(p).

Question: Are there faster ways to search for prime candidates of this form? How much trial division should I do if this is even the correct approach?

Comment: Hey thanks Austin. It did though. for p in range(1+10**1000,10**10000,2):
trialdivandfermat(p) goes at the end.

Comment: I can recommend some books to look at. Hans Riesel, Prime Numbers and Computer Methods for Factorization; Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming; Crandall and Pomerance, Prime Numbers, a Computational Perspective.

Comment: And I can recommend a program called [OpenPFGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/) which implements pretty well optimized versions of some of the algorithms for checking and proving primality of big numbers.